# Conclusions from rejecting the null hypothesis with two-sided test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose that we have samples $x$ and $y$, where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the $i$-th subject's responses to the first and the second treatment respectively.

Then, we perform a two-sided statistical test, trying to reject the null hypothesis that *both treatments have the same effect*. For example, the Wilcoxon signed ranked test can be used.

Then, we find the neutral value $s_0$ of statistic $s$ that used in the test (the value that one would get if $x_i = y_i$ for all $i$). Let's assume that $s > s_0$ means that the first treatment is better than the second.

Suppose that the obtained value $s_c = s(x, y)$ is greater than $s_0$ and the null hypothesis was rejected.

I wonder whether I can conclude that the first treatment is better than the second, since the negation of the null hypothesis in our case is that *the treatments have different effect*.

Comment: See the 2nd paragraph of my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140517/17230). Less formally: if you can reject the null, you might feel entitled to cast about for better hypotheses among those comprising the (composite) alternative.

Comment: @Scortchi A. We can perfom a two-sided test and hope that $p< \alpha$, or we can perform two one-sided tests and hope that $p< 2\alpha$. It the latter case, we have to use some kind of multiple-hypothesis testing correction, e.g. Bonferroni correction, so we hope that $2p< 2\alpha$, but this condition is already satisfied. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. There's a little more to say about discrete test statistics, but that's the idea.