# Definition of statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance, definition

Consider the following definition of statistical significance:

> Statistical significance is a characteristic of a statistic viewed in light of an (implicit or explicit) null hypothesis and a given significance level. It reflects whether the statistic belongs to the rejection region or the acceptance region defined by the null hypothesis and the significance level. The statistic is then statistically significant or not statistically significant, respectively.

Is the definition valid, or are there any problems with it?

(It is quite different from e.g. [our tag description](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/statistical-significance/info) for statistical significance.)

Comment: The tag wiki could use some clarification, because it is really trying to describe the p-value.  Although closely related to significance, it's not the same thing.

Comment: @whuber, indeed, this is what I thought. What about replacing it with what I have in the post, maybe with a tweak or two if needed?

Answer (score 0):

The tag description has been changed to the following:

> Statistical significance is a characteristic of a statistic viewed in light of an (implicit or explicit) null hypothesis and a given significance level. It reflects whether the statistic belongs to the rejection region or the acceptance region defined by the null hypothesis and the significance level. The statistic is then statistically significant or not statistically significant, respectively.

Comment: But let's recognize that "statistically significant" means almost nothing.  It is an arbitrary construct that invites users to make the "absence of evidence is not evidence of absence" error among other things.  In light of the fact that the rejection region is an arbitrary construct not tied to decision theory, I'd like to see a definition that at least mentions the word "arbitrary" and points to the ASA statement on p-values.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Why do you say the rejection region is unrelated to decision theory?

Comment: The Bayes optimum decision is the decision that optimizes the expected utility/loss/cost function.  P-values have no relationship to that since they condition on the decision ($H_0$) you are trying to make in the first place.  Expected utility is the integral of the posterior probability convolved with the utility whereas the P-value is a probability about _data_ not about $\theta$.

Comment: I got the impression the rejection region is not all that arbitrary: e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/447510, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483685.

Comment: In this situation I have, reluctantly, to disagree with Prof. Harrell, who seems to adopt a Bayesian perspective that is a little too extreme.  The decision-theoretic foundations of statistical significance have been rigorously developed by Wald, Kiefer, and others.  As they clearly showed, the rejection region is far from "arbitrary."  Statistical significance (and the p-value) has a principled, logical meaning.  The problems with p-values stem from misunderstandings, abuse, and inherent limitations rather than arbitrariness in the theory or their construction.